# Print indexes of lists of list as the main list (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing, printing, get

i want to print indexes elements of lists of the list.

i have a list as below

```
list1=[["a","b","c"],["a","b"],["a","b","c","d"]]
```

what i expected

```
expectedlist=[[0,1,2],[0,1],[0,1,2,3]]
```

I tried this code

```
list1=[["a","b","c"],["a","b"],["a","b","c","d"]]
a=[]

for i,v in enumerate(list1):
    for k,r in enumerate(v):
        a+=[k]

print(a)
```

but it printed just a list.

> > > > [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
> > > >
> > > > expectedlist=[[0,1,2],[0,1],[0,1,2,3]]

Comment: Why is the final list `[0,1,2,3,4]`? Yo have only 4 elements

Comment: How to want to handle repeated elements? Should `["a", "b", "a"]` produce `[0, 1, 0]` or `[0, 1, 2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using a single list whereas your final output is a nested list.

Therefore, you need two lists.

```
a = []
for i, v in enumerate(list1): 
    b = []
    for k, r in enumerate(v): 
        b+=[k] # Also b.append(k)
    a.append(b)    

print(a)
# [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply get the `len` of the sublists and generate a `list` out of it with `range`. Should be quite faster.

```
>>> list1 = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]

>>> [list(range(len(sub))) for sub in list1]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
>>> ls = [["a","b","c"],["a","b"],["a","b","c","d"]]
>>> [[i for i,v in enumerate(el)] for el in ls]

[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension, like this :

```
>>> list1=[["a","b","c"],["a","b"],["a","b","c","d"]]
>>> [[k.index(i) for i in k] for k in list1]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use a `map`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: list(range(len(x))), list1))
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```

If the values are unique:

```
>>> [list(map(i.index, i)) for i in list1]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```